# Using Logitech G13 LUA script to output a string to a desktop application

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Due to an injury, I'm using a G13 to automate work tasks, one of which is entering the current date, in one of a few formats. Using the online compiler here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php, I was able to figure out how to get and format the date, but what I can't find is an output method that will send the string to Word, Chrome, Notepad, etc. - whatever the active window is. Outputting it to the log or LCD doesn't get it where I need it. Print doesn't output to the active window, and io.write gives the following error: [string "LuaVM"]:11: attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value). Os.date gave a similar error, that's why it's commented out.

My testbed code:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg)
    
    local MKeyState = GetMKeyState("lhc")
    --OutputLogMessage(MKeyState)

    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 14 and MKeyState == 2) then
        local date = GetDate("%m/%d/%y") --os.date("%m/%d/%y")
        OutputLogMessage(date)
        OutputLCDMessage(date)
        io.write(date)
        --print(os.date("%m/%d/%y"))
    end
end
```

My testbed output:

```
event = PROFILE_DEACTIVATED, arg = 0
event = PROFILE_ACTIVATED, arg = 0
event = G_PRESSED, arg = 14
10/22/21[string "LuaVM"]:11: attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value)

event = G_RELEASED, arg = 14
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts you might have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, one has to use the function `PressAndReleaseKey` with each character of the string. It is further complicated by the circumstance that this function doesn't take the character itself as an argument, but rather a *keyname* (see the *Table of scancodes and keynames* in the API docs). For your `date` string, this could work (I haven't tested it):

```
        for c in date:gmatch '.' do
            if c == '/' then
                c = "slash"
            end
            PressAndReleaseKey(c)
        end
```

Comment: So that being the case, in order to output the date, I'd need it to read the nth character in the string for n = 1 to string_length, determine what key code correlates to that character of the string, then PressAndRelease(that_key)?

Comment: Yes, that's what the above snippet is supposed to do. Fortunately, the _keynames_ of the digits are identical to the respective digits, so they don't need translation.